# How can I display special characters returned by child_process.exec?

Tags: node.js, encoding, exec

I'm using `child_process.exec` to run a command that includes in its output some special characters, but these are invariably interpreted by Node.js as replacement characters (`\uFFFD`). The following snippet should demonstrate this behavior sufficiently:

```
require("child_process").exec("echo äëïöü", function(stderr, stdout) {
    console.log(stdout);
});
```

Is there any way I can determine what the special characters returned in the output actually are? I'm using Windows, if it's relevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default `encoding` for [`exec()`](https://nodejs.org/docs/latest/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) is `utf8`. You can override this default and get raw Buffers containing the literal binary bytes by setting `encoding: 'buffer'`:

```
require("child_process").exec("echo äëïöü",
                              { encoding: 'buffer' },
                              function(err, stdout, stderr) {
   // `stdout` and `stderr` are Buffer instances
  console.dir(stdout);
});
```

Comment: What's the best way to map the raw bytes to their corresponding Unicode characters? For instance, the Buffer returned in this example is populated by octets represented as `132`, `137`, `139`, `148`, and `129`. How do I translate that into the string "äëïöü"?

Comment: It depends on your environment. You might look at `process.env.LC_CTYPE` or `process.env.LANG` or execute `locale charmap` in a child process to determine the current encoding being used. If it's not UTF-8 or any other encoding that node has built-in support for, you will need to look into using the `iconv`/`iconv-lite` modules on npm to do conversions for you.

Comment: Got it, thanks! I used `iconv-lite` to decode using my current code page (437) and it works perfectly.